# Which Menace area is the easiest to escape?

Tags: fallen-london

In Fallen London, death will not release you — *even if you die.*

Racking up too much Scandal, Suspicion, Wounds, or Nightmares will ship you off to a Place Of Menace: the Tomb-Colonies, New Newgate Prison, a river-crossing ride with the Boatman, or the Royal Bethlehem Hotel/Mirror-Marches, respectively.

I was surprised to see [this forum post](http://community.failbettergames.com/topic7535-hesperidean-cider-charity-auction.aspx?Page=1#post58287), which suggests that the place of Wounds is the easiest to escape and Wounds itself is the easiest Menace to manage; this runs directly counter to my experience.  (The post references Hesperidian Cider, which has more details [in this auction](http://con-or-bust.org/2014/02/hesperidean-cider-in-fallen-london/).) I've found that Wounds is either expensive or inconvenient to reduce, that most Wound-reduction actions only take off a single point of Wounds, and that the Boatman's ride is time-consuming to escape.

So, I ask: *without spending Fate/Nex*, which place of Menace is the easiest to escape, and what's the trick of it? Which place is the hardest to escape, and what limits your ability to leave quickly? (Please mention all four places of Menace in your answer.)

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that the Mirror Marches are both the easiest to escape from and the most profitable to visit, mostly because they almost never penalize you, except in "Is Someone There?" CPs. I can get out of the Mirror Marches in twenty actions, if I'm not extremely unlucky or curious about something.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your stats. If your Watchful is within a proper range, playing chess with the Boatman can get you free fairly quickly.

On the other hand, if you get lucky with Opportunity cards, you can escape New Newgate in as few as three or so turns (by using the shiv and related cards).

Comment: Playing chess with the Boatman is, ultimately, limited. Chess now uses the *The Boatman's Opponent* quality to determine its difficulty, and as that rises, the Boatman gets harder - independent of your stats, I think. So you'll eventually run out of effective Chess actions, which just leaves you with the much-less-effective Dice With The Boatman action.